# Desabilitar ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY de vez

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Como faço para que ao desabilitar o ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ele permaneça desabilitado de vez? Pergunto porque já fiz os passos abaixo:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

e também direto do **phpmyadmin**:

- Selecionei o localhost;
- Cliquei em Variáveis;
- Fui em SQL Modes;
- Removi ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY;

O problema é que sempre que reinicio o note, ele volta a ficar ativo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde, em seu terminal execute o seguinte comando.

`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%sql_mode%'`;

copie o conteúdo, exceto  `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Feito isso, procure pelo arquivo de configuração do `MySQL` que é o `my.cnf`, adicione ao arquivo a seguinte linha:

`sql_mode=[conteudo_copiado]`

Reinicie o serviço do `MySQL` e pronto, vai estar padrão.

Comment: Olá arllondias. Certo. Procurei o arquivo `my.ini` e não encontrei. A única referência do Mysql que encontrei foi em `/etc/mysql/` e o arquivo que encontrei próximo do que você mencionou foi `my.cnf`. Seria isso? Se não for esse arquivo, onde posso encontrar o `my.ini`?

Comment: isso, desculpa, escrevi errado ali, editei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado arllondias.

Comment: Por nada, @Fox.11

Answer (score 0):

Só para reforçar a resposta do arllondias, no meu caso tive que colocar dessa forma no arquivo my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Observem que coloquei `[mysqld]` e também dentro de aspas o novo valor do sql_mode. Após isso, reinicie o mysql: `service mysql restart`